# How to optimize for time?

Tags: performance, time, time-complexity

I'm trying to understand if there is a difference in speed when executing the following lines of code in a computer program:

1. myarray[1] = 5; return myarray[1];
2. myarray[0] = 5; return myarray[0];
3. x = 5; return x;
4. x = 5; y = x; return y;
5. return 5;

From what I understand, arrays are basically pointers (variables that store the memory addresses of other variables). Therefore (1) and (2) should be the same speed, but slower than (3), (4) and (5).

(5) should be the fastest, (3) should be slower than (5) because there is an equal sign, and (4) should be slower than (3) because there are two equal signs that need to be handled.

Would this be right?

Comment: At least if the variables involved (`myarray`, `x`,` y`) are all local to the function that's returning, a decent optimizing compiler will normally be able to "see through" the other assignments, and they'll all end up essentially identical.

Comment: it depends on the language... but more importantly: if you ask a question like this, you really shouldn't worry about it. on your level of understanding, it doesn't matter. make your code correct and readable.

Comment: To add to @JerryCoffin, it also depends what your compiler/interpreter does to this. For instance, if myarray is local to the current function, it might reckognize the futility of 1 and 2, and optimize it to 5. You really shouldn't worry about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give a context what myarray, x and y are. Without that context, the question cannot be answered in any meaningful way. The extra assignments might have no side effects that cannot be optimised away.

Basically, looking at speed optimisation at this elementary level is completely pointless. If you want to look at speed, you need code that is substantial enough that the execution time can be measured. You cannot measure the time of one or two simple statements on a modern processor.